# Whitespace take up space in CSS grid layout

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the `.text()` function to replace text in a div, situated in a CSS grid layout, if `$(this).is(':contains("N/A")')` returns `true`. My issue is that I'd like the div to continue to occupy space, as if it did contain text. However, it does not do so and my container does not occupy the full height of the space that it does if text is present. Is there any way to do this without specifying the `height` of each row div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `visibility: hidden` to hide an element while keeping the boundaries:

```js
function hide() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].className = 'hidden';
}
```

```css
div {
  background: orange;
  border: solid 3px black;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
<button onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if($(this).is(':contains("N/A")'))
{
    var w = $(this).width();
    $(this).attr('style','min-width:'+w);
    $(this).text('');
}
```